# Why is my Java app only fetching an old version of an online file?

Tags: java, caching, webserver

I have [a file online with information about some Minecraft blocks](http://prog.bhstudios.org/bhmi/database/get). When I first made this test file, I gave it three rows and a header expiration date of next Sunday (whenever that may be). My Java app fetched this no problem!

However, now I have inserted three more rows into this small database and changed the expiration date to last week, but **my Java app still displays the original 3**! When I visit the page in a browser, it gives me the full, current table. **How come the Java app is still only fetching the old version?**

The key code:

```
InputStream in;
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection(); // url is a valid java.net.URL object
urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlc.setDoInput(true);
urlc.setDoOutput(false);
urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "BHMI/3.0.0 (+http://prog.BHStudios.org/BHMI) Java/" + System.getProperty("java.version") + "(" + System.getProperty("java.vm.name") + ")"); // GoDaddy blocks Java clients, so we must have a custom user agent string
urlc.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
urlc.setUseCaches(false);
urlc.connect();
System.out.println("Connection successful! Database expires " + new Date(urlc.getExpiration()));
in = urlc.getInputStream();
int data;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((data = in.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char) data);
System.out.println("RAW DATA:\r\n"+sb);
```

Sample output:

```
Connection successful! Database expires Tue Nov 26 00:09:05 EST 2013
RAW DATA:
minecraft:air,Air,0,0,,
minecraft:stone,Stone,1,0,2,
minecraft:grass,Grass,2,0,,
```

I **cleared the Java network cache** through Windows control panel, **and all caches and temporary files** on my local machine with CCleaner, but this still happens. Heck, it happens across machines, so it can't be that. **I've cleared all edge caches from my server**, so it also can't be that.
I've even tried downloading the file after telling my browser to use my Java app's User-Agent string, and it fetched all 5 lines.

### Request Headers

From my Java app:

```
GET /http/bhstudios/v2/prog/bhmi/database/get HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: BHMI/3.0.0 (+http://prog.BHStudios.org/BHMI) Java/1.7.0_45(Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Host: BHStudios.org
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

From Chrome, spoofing the same User-Agent string:

```
GET /prog/bhmi/database/get/ HTTP/1.1
Host: prog.bhstudios.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: BHMI/3.0.0 (+http://prog.BHStudios.org/BHMI) Java/1.7.0_45(Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=dc9d0394ed55ebb1214fcbb5fc825626b1385426208553; visitorId=5293ed2b758cb1b5620000b0
```

### Response Headers

From my Java app:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 02:17:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4432e3d81cf9e5b9393f2cca483e4b2d1385432256651; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.bhstudios.org; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=IE8
CF-RAY: d33155416660862
```

Note that suspicious cookie expiration `expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT`. Could this be the cause?

I also note that, when fetching from Chrome and using the same User-Agent string as my app, the header is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 17:30:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 10:30:01 America/Phoenix
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=BHMI_Items_Vanilla_172.csv
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=IE8
CF-RAY: d408b3c56320098
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

which is the intended header, with an expiration date of last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... I was requesting the wrong file.
Sorry for wasting your time >.<

As the header shows, I was addressing an old URL scheme, `/http/bhstudios/v2/prog/bhmi/database/get`, when I wanted `/prog/bhmi/database/get`

Answer (score 2):

You have to put in your request header info that you are looking for data that are not cached:

```
  urlc.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control","no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
  urlc.setRequestProperty("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
```

Comment: It already has `header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate'); header('Pragma: public');`. Is the rest that necessary?

Comment: Depends on your server. Try it.

Comment: Actually, since this work in your browser, use WireShark, or even FireBug or some similar web developer tool to check headers that makes work without cache.

Comment: I've changed the headers in both the request and the file and still no change :/
Will download WireShark now

Comment: in your web browser you have tools for checking request/responses. Fierbug is widely used. Chrome has web developer, and ie has webdeveloper. You can monitor headers also from there.

Comment: Wireshark gave me this telling piece of the header: `Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4432e3d81cf9e5b9393f2cca483e4b2d1385432256651; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.bhstudios.org; HttpOnly`

Comment: You should check request headers of proper working requests, not response headers. Post them.